# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.2.29.0'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, vsto

I'm working on a VSTO Outlook Add-In built using Visual Studio 2010. I don't have Nuget Package Manager installed. When I run the Add-In in Outlook I get the exception:

`Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.2.29.0'`

I simply cloned the original project from GitHub. When I run it in Debug using Visual Studio, it works fine. But, once I publish to setup.exe and install, I get the above issue. The reference to `System.Net.Http` is already added.

My `app.config` file for Outlook version 2007 is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="Outlook2007.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.29.0" newVersion="2.2.29.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup><userSettings>
    <PluginOutlook2007.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="TokenSettingNeed" serializeAs="String">
        <value>else imported dll settings don t work</value>
      </setting>
    </PluginOutlook2007.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

In the same solution, there's a second project targeting Outlook 2010. `app.comfig` for that is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="PluginOutlook2010.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.29.0" newVersion="2.2.29.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <userSettings>
    <PluginOutlook2010.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="testval" serializeAs="String">
        <value>34</value>
      </setting>
    </PluginOutlook2010.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Thenb there's a third project in the same solution (which has the business logic shared by the 2007 and 2010 projects with the `app.config` below. The `System.Net.Http` namespace is actually used by this third project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="PluginOutlookCommon.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
      // some stuff here
    </userSettings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" /></startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.29.0" newVersion="2.2.29.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by commenting out the

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.29.0" newVersion="2.2.29.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

part in the `app.config` file.